# Django fails to loaddata with deserialization error

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am running Wagtail which runs on django and when running the `dumpdata` the following occurs

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent 2 --output dumps.json
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: wagtailimages_uploadedimage
```

After that I delete the sqlite database and remove the migrations from the apps `migrations` directory so I can have an empty database and test the dumped data. After running `migrate` I execute  `loaddata dump1.json` and the following error comes up

```
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 68, in Deserializer
    objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-professional/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "/opt/pycharm-professional/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/user/Desktop/projects/mytestwebapp/dump1.json':
```

I have tried also to exclude some of the things i dont need while dumping, using the following

```
dumpdata --natural-foreign --indent 2 -e contenttypes -e auth.permission -e wagtailcore.groupcollectionpermission -e wagtailcore.grouppagepermission -e wagtailimages.rendition -e sessions > dump1.json
```

But it didnt make any difference.

The application is a simple blog following the demo shown [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.9/getting_started/tutorial.html).

Comment: Is the fixture named `data.json` or `dump1.json`? You are using both names in your question

Comment: sorry for the confusion, just copied the command from the terminal and didnt realize it had different name. You can consider the fixture name the same as it didnt made any differemce. I am renaming it in the question though for the sake of consistency

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `--output` instead of `>` to avoid sending console(stdout) debugging info to your dumped data, also exclude the irrelevant models

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --indent 2 -e contenttypes -e auth.permission -e wagtailcore.groupcollectionpermission -e wagtailcore.grouppagepermission -e wagtailimages.rendition -e sessions -e wagtailimages.uploadedimage --output dumps.json
```

Comment: It did not work. I have also updated the question with an error output which weirdly does not occur in every execution of the dumpdata. The error is `Unable to serialize database: no such table: wagtailimages_uploadedimage`

Comment: @kampias no idea, I used the above command for my site, it works fine, and I usually use this command on app level,not whole site.  for example, for product app,  I use:  `python manage.py dumpdata  product --indent 2  --output product.json`,  can you test if the single app work?  also test if  `exclude` works... `-e wagtailimages.uploadedimage`?

Comment: yes it worked. Initially i tried the `-e wagtailimages.uploadedimage` on its own but more errors came up. The final command that worked and I was able to restore the database later on with `loaddata` was the following : `dumpdata --natural-foreign --indent 2 -e contenttypes -e auth.permission -e wagtailcore.groupcollectionpermission -e wagtailcore.grouppagepermission -e wagtailimages.rendition -e sessions -e wagtailimages.uploadedimage --output dumps.json`. If you would like, edit your answer above so I can accept it

Comment: adding --natural-foreign helps to proceed loaddata, but I meet another error.
Could not load users.Profile(pk=407): UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id
I have Profile model with one-to-one to auth.Users.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output, the dumped data is empty thus it throws the following error.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Ways to dump your data:

1. Drop your database by deleting your sqlite database file
2. Delete your migrations folder
3. `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. `python manage.py migrate`
5. Try add some sample data by creating a user or other data
6. Run dump data again `python manage.py dumpdata -output my_dumps.json`

Then, check the my_dumps.json file, if there are some data inside, then you can try load your data using
`python manage.py loaddata my_dumps.json`

Comment: dumped data is not empty. The dump1.json upon inspection contains a lot of data